# Upload & store images to the server

Tags: php, image, storage

I am looking for a way to store profile images (flyers) on the filesystem for events (activities).
For the following reasons, I'm planning to use base64 encoded images to send as json to the back end:

- It is only for profile images with limited file size up to 150kB (my webapp doesn't deal with images further than that at this point);
- The simplest solution for web browser compatibility;

The best answer (most upvoted) I have found so far is this one: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/95444/storing-a-million-images-in-the-filesystem
As there may be many events, there may be many images over time.

The first suggestion is:

> Do not store the actual path to database. Better to store the image's
>   sequence number to database and have function that can generate path
>   from the sequence number. e.g:
>
> File path = generatePathFromSequenceNumber(sequenceNumber);

From this sequence number, I'll be able to derive the path & filename to store in my database.
This may be a stupid question, but how do I derive a sequence number from a base64 encoded string?

Comment: what you want you need to store image to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For the following reasons, I'm planning to use base64 encoded images to send as json to the back end:
>
> - It is only for profile images with limited file size up to 150kB (my webapp doesn't deal with images further than that at this point);
> - The simplest solution for web browser compatibility;

Remember that there is a 33% overhead for storage of base64 encoded data.  That isn't trivial if you have a large number of items, even if they are only 150KB.  Base64 is also not remotely the simplest solution for web browser compatibility... the original binary image is.

I strongly suggest reconsidering your plan here.  If you store encoded images, you're wasting disk space and preventing yourself from doing anything with the image unless you decode it first.

> This may be a stupid question, but how do I derive a sequence number from a base64 encoded string?

You wouldn't.  That sequence number is the ID number in your database of the image.  You have a database somewhere with extra data on these image assets, right?

Comment: Hm, okay. I'm working on a pure javascript application with REST interface; it appears that submitting the file would be possible with formdata, but it isn't supported by IE9. And damn, it's the id from the record... I totally didn't get that!

Comment: @KimGysen Even if you were to base64 for transport, I'd still store the original binary on disk for flexibility.  If you had a special use case where for optimization the base64 made sense, you could do that, but that would be a very special case.  Your API can return URLs of the image.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, what I could do is upload the base64 path, and then just decode it at the server? Sorry for the supplementary question.

Comment: @KimGysen Yes, exactly.  I wouldn't upload base64 to begin with though... file uploads tend to be especially slow for users, and adding 33% overhead with no real benefit doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  But if you had to do it, then yes decode that base64 server-side and store the real binary.

Comment: I'll check the alternative options. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

The sequence ID would probably be the key for the record in the database that you create, if you take that suggestion.

Using a three level tree is also a good suggestion.

However, instead of directly taking the sequence number and turning it into an incrementing path, I would some how generate a hash or something semi random representing the image and use that for the path (if not a hash, then perhaps a random hex string, or a UUID).

If you convert the sequence ID directly into a numbered file name as shown in that answer, you will end up writing 10000 files to the first directory before you start to fill the second directory.  I think it is a good idea to try to achieve a random distribution across your top level directories.  When you get to 1 million files, why pay the full cost of reading through 1000 files in a directory across leaf directories (because that is all that will be used) when you could instead have them evenly distributed across all the leaf directories.  If nothing else, it lets you easily spread the tree out over multiple file systems (perhaps because they are on different servers) down the road.

So, in my own application (at work), keys are UUIDs, so for instance, my first key might be `aa082512eeb64694a24c16601b4d9f05`.  This will then be placed in `aa0/825/aa082512eeb64694a24c16601b4d9f05.jpg`.  I'm not sure how many files the project has so far, but we have passed 2TB of imagery stored (mostly 1920x1080, not limited to 150KB files).

BTW, w.r.t. your base64 encoding, we instead get data about the image from the user separately from uploading the image.  We perform the actual upload in an iframe.  It isn't the most pleasant, but it allowed us to upload images directly without bloating the encoding while still updating the form and being responsive to the user in the main window.  I believe there exist libraries to do this sort of thing for you, I don't recall at the moment which one we used.

Our plan for the future is to add feature detection code and only use the iframe for IE9 and use something a bit more modern in IE10, Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Comment: Haha, still laughing mao, looking for a solution to convert the base64. Thanks, I see your logic and it makes a lot of sense. For uploading the image, I'm still looking into the different options. If I could find a cross-browser library with a general solution, this would be nice.